# Do the symbols used in the TV series Evil, actually exist?

Tags: realism, reference, evil

In Robert & Michelle King's latest TV series, [*Evil*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_(TV_series)), a priest in training, a forensic psychologist/mother of four, and skeptic techie-carpenter/contractor investigate for the Vatican: the potential for the supernatural, including the demonic, contesting if some people may be demons sent by the devil!

The series then has an ongoing Dan Brown *Da Vinci Code-esque* or *Alias-like* mythology, where there are "60" symbols associated with "The 60" demons that are said to arrive on Earth and possibly pave way for the Apocalypse. Not to mention the character Leland Townsend, who may or may not be the devil incarnate himself, whom is associated with one of these symbols.

So my question is, are these symbols (diagrams/scriptures of them) completely fictional and made exclusively for the TV Series or did Robert & Michelle King and other writers/producers actually take them from somewhere from our real world?

---

<sub>NOTE: I'm looking for a screencap for the symbols, but haven't found any yet.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real world reason for a "NO" answer is - You don't want to have your show blocked in any place because you used a symbol someone recognize as evil. Monster drink "praising devil" case.

BUT, I've found in one episode (8th) that the "60 sigils" are very close to 72 sigils of demons in *Ars Goetia*. So I looked and compared a sigil from the show.

[image]

It looks very much like the sigil from the real world book.

[image]

So they probably took *Ars Goetia* as an inspiration for creating the symbols. It's easier to just change existing one and KNOW it's not "real" instead of making up one and being accused of using something that already exist and is used for "evil worshipping".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just to clarify, when I asked about them being "real" I didn't necessarily mean in the same "evil" or demonic context as the series--I was interested in them in any context that they might exist. But this seems like the right answer and it is surprising that they might be inspired by demons from The Lesser Key of Solomon...